# override django-allauth default forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-allauth

I want to override the default forms of django-allauth in order to change\add default widget attributes, class variables without changing the initial code of allauth form. 
How can I do that?

My workspace:

1) installed django-allauth, as a package through pip;

2) configured settings, according to the recommendations of the project on github;

3) locally created templates signin, signup;

4) created forms.py, which defines a child class forms django-allauth

```
from allauth.account import SigninForm

class mySigninForm (SigninForm):
     username = ...//override variable
```

Is this right way?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, overriding the allauth form class is the easiest and most generic way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd like to use the methods or functionalities provided by the allauth forms then overriding the form classes like you currently are is your best bet.

```
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm
from django import forms
from myapp.forms import widgets


class MyLoginForm(LoginForm):

    // Override attributes
    existing_field = forms.CharField(widget=widgets.CustomWidget())

    // Add Custom Attributes
    new_field = forms.CharField(widget=widgets.CustomWidget())
```

If you want a completely custom form, you can use a custom django form and then use it in the view. For Example:

#### forms

```
from django import forms
from myapp.forms import widgets

class MyLoginForm(forms.Form):
    // Add atributes and methods
    some_field = forms.CharField(widget=widgets.CustomWidget())
```

#### views

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from myapp.forms import MyLoginForm

LoginUser(FormView):
    form = MyLoginForm
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But, how can I add attributes to parent widget without override variable in child form class?

Comment: I have updated the answer with how to use a custom widget with both overriden and new fields.

Comment: How can you override the `allauth` login form this way?

Comment: @Amyth I tried this but I get stuck, maybe at a stupid point, but how do I refer to the view?; As I need to replace the allauth url probably I will put in a url before the allauth url; Something like: url(r'^accounts/login/$', view=views.MyLoginForm.as_view(), name='myloginform')    except that this does not work... Please suggest.

Comment: @musicformellons Yes. If you override the view you'll either need to override the existing url or create a new one to access the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can override any (or all) of the `allauth` default templates by creating your own tree of template files.

The naming of the hierarchy must match `allauth`, e.g. this is from my project:

```
allauthdemo/templates/
├── allauth
│   ├── account
│   └── socialaccount
├── my
├── other
├── template
└── dirs
```

The template settings in `settings.py` must include those dirs, e.g.:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'allauthdemo', 'templates', 'allauth'),
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'allauthdemo', 'templates'),
    ],
    ...
```

[This allauth demo on github](https://github.com/aellerton/demo-allauth-bootstrap) shows how to do it. Disclaimer: I wrote that demo.